# My fan turns off after a few seconds

Tags: 11.10, hardware, fan

Can you please help, I cannot get the fan to come on at all when running 11.10, it works fine in windows so obviuosly not the fan itself, it comes on for about 5 seconds when   laptop initially turned on, then will not come on after that, even if left on untill cpu gets so hot laptop  crashes.

Comment: Laptop brand and modell?

Comment: Hi, it,s a acer 5315

Comment: Do you have proprietary drivers installed?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).